# Emberjs bug? Observer called when value is changed, but other bindings to same value is not updated

Tags: data-binding, ember.js

I have an observer to a value "App.selectedValue". I also have another Ember object that has a binding (App.someObj.appValueBinding) to App.selectedValue. However, when my observer is called, the binding of App.someObj is not updated.

This is illustrated in http://jsfiddle.net/Ur2Qj/8/

In the jsfiddle, you can see in the Chrome debugger or FireBug, that App.selectedValue and App.someObj.appValue have different values, even tho' the latter is bound to the former.

Seems like the binding should be updated when the observer is called. Is this expected behavior in Emberjs or is it a bug? Is there a work-around?

Thanks for looking at this!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at this: http://jsfiddle.net/ud3323/GUHCD/ (in JavaScript; I don't like CoffeeScript... sorry).

The two main things you've got wrong here is not using `get()` and `set()` properly and in your observer you need to set `App.someController.content` after the end of the current runloop (which means after all the other bindings have taken place). You do this by using `Ember.run.next()`. You could also use `Ember.run.sync()` there as well.

Oh and you need to use jQuery 1.7.1. Version 1.5.2 is not compatible with Ember.

Comment: Thanks, Roy! Most of the EmberJS.com doc examples use assignments without set(). Is that wrong?

Comment: For singletons (like controllers) you don't have to as long as you pay attention to the order in which they are created. To be safe, I do regardless as a best practice. It just eliminates possible headaches... especially in large apps. But you should ALWAYS to use `get()` and `set()` when dealing with properties on Ember objects. If there is somewhere in the docs that isn't submit a pull request on the docs to fix it.